# Why does one-definition-rule-use (odr-use) depend on the context?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, one-definition-rule

Given the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    static constexpr float a = 2.0f;
};

// non-const reference to make it more explicit - same behaviour
template<class T> constexpr inline T square(T& x)
{
    return x * x;
}

int main() {
    /*constexpr*/ float val = square(A::a);
    std::cout << val;
}
```

This program fails to link with `undefined reference to 'A::a'` (always with clang, only on -O0 with g++), however it links properly if I uncomment the `constexpr` from the `val` declaration.

So far I understand that `constexpr` can't be odr-used without explicit definition in one of the unit files, but I don't understand why does it work while assigning to the `constexpr`.

It seems like those two cases are handled differently depending on the context. But why? Shouldn't the compiler just evaluate this function at compile time in both cases?

Comment: The snippet you posted compiles fine both in GCC and CLANG.

Comment: please don't use uncommon acronyms in title.

Comment: @101010 remove `constexpr ` from `constexpr float val = square(A::a);` to see the problem

Comment: What on earth is "one-definition-rule-use"?

Comment: @Andrew ...that completely misses the point. I know what odr-use is just fine.

Comment: @UmNyobe: "odr-use" is a technical term of art in the C++ Standard. It may be unusual, but it's accurate, and it's something you can look up in the index, unlike the expanded form.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does odr-use depend on the context?

It doesn't. `square(A::a)` odr-uses `A::a`, period.

Most ODR violations, however, are not required to be diagnosed, and this is no exception.

> Shouldn't the compiler just evaluate this function at compile time in both cases?

The initializer of a `constexpr` variable must be evaluated at compile time. (Well, not quite, but the compiler must be evaluate it to the point where it can determine that it is a valid constant expression, at which point it might as well just do the whole thing.) For a non-`constexpr` local variable, there's no such guarantee.

Comment: So I should rather ask: "Why does odr-use work at compile time?". Where would a pointer for example point to? The program is not running. Does it point to some compiler structures?
Why doesn't it simply fail in such case? Why does standard allow such constructs?

Comment: @pkubik sure, you can create a question that asks that.  Make it a bit more polished, and attach it to a real problem, ideally.  This question, however, is not that one!